# How to get accurate path of the uploaded file in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to upload file from my local system using  `<INPUT NAME="file1" TYPE="file" >` in jsp file.and i try to get actual path of the uploaded file with the file name. but i can't get correct path.

I am using the bellow code

```
String filename = request.getParameter("file1");           

System.out.println(filename);
String r=  request.getRealPath(filename);
```

Output :
/home/raptor/vinoth/vinoth.k/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/wtpwebapps/LoginMonitor/file.txt
instead of /home/raptor/vinoth/file.txt

Every time it search the file in my web application folder

but the about code not giving actual path. i am using firefox  browser. can any one help me to fix this problem??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What output you are getting for String r ?

Comment: @NinadPingale i am getting /home/raptor/vinoth/vinoth.k/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/wtpwebapps/LoginMonitor/file.txt.

Comment: I might be mistaking but I think that you are selecting file, webapp performs it's upload and puts to your `/home/raptor/vinoth/vinoth.k/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/wtpwebapps/LoginMonitor/file.txt instead of /home/raptor/vinoth/` folder. That's why you got this path.

Comment: @WhiteAngel i need to upload file any where in my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for what purpose you want to have real path?
if you want it to upload/download on server.please refer this link
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/servlet-upload-file-and-download-file-example.html

this link contains a web application which has both operation for uploading and downloading a file from local system.

Comment: i need to browse the xl file in my local system and than i need to upload the xl file content in my database. i already did upload the xl file into db with static path. i need to upload file from dynamic path